# Differentiability of Busemann function

Tags: riemannian-geometry

For any Busemann function $\mathrm{b}$ of the ray $\gamma$, at any point $x$, there is at least one Busemann ray passing $x$, denoted as $\gamma_x$. If the Busemann ray $\gamma_x$ is unique at $x$, why $\mathrm{b}$ is differentiable at $x$? The above results was stated without proof on page 559 of Sormani's paper "Busemann functions on manifolds with lower bounds on Ricci curvature and minimal volume growth. J. Differential Geom. 48 (1998), no. 3, 557–585.".

Comment: You should add more detail to the question, for instance, maybe you also know that there are no conjugate points along any of the geodesic rays which are the gradient lines of ${\mathbf b}$. The standard reference to $C^1$-smoothness of Busemann functions is: J. Eschenburg, Horosphere and the stable part of the geodesic flow, Math. Z. 151 (1977),
237–251.

Comment: @Misha, thanks, I have add more details into the question. I will check Eschenburg.